# Mapping an API's setting IDs to setting names with class methods, enabling clearer utilization

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, python-requests

I'm trying to access an API using the requests library in as clean a manner as possible. The API is accessing various settings of various devices. I'd like to keep my code as readable and comprehensible as possible, thus I want to avoid setting up my API access functions too abstractly. Therefore, instead of `setting_101` I want to edit settings by their associated name.

I reckon a class mapping a the various setting names to their values is the most desirable approach, but given my inexperience with classes I would appreciate some feedback on my attempt.

My ultimate goal is to have a class allowing me to simply access a setting, once an instance is setup, through `read.setting_name()`. Previously I simply defined individual functions for every setting which while functional was massively inefficient and a bit of an anti-pattern.

The code below is my attempt at implementing the desired functionality. It works, but it still feels a bit 'rough'.

```py
import requests

class SettingReader:
    def __init__(self, domain, headers, device_serial):
        self.domain = domain
        self.headers = headers
        self.device_serial = device_serial
        self.setting_ids = {
            'setting_A': 1,
            'setting_B': 2,
            'setting_C': 3,
        }

    def read_setting_A(self):
        return self._read_setting(self.setting_ids['setting_A'])

    def read_setting_B(self):
        return self._read_setting(self.setting_ids['setting_B'])

    def read_setting_C(self):
        return self._read_setting(self.setting_ids['setting_C'])

    def _read_setting(self, setting_id):
        url = f'{self.domain}/device/{self.device_serial}/settings/{setting_id}/read'
        response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=self.headers)
        return response

domain = "https://my_dummy_api.com"
headers = {"Authorization": "my_token"}

reader = SettingReader(domain, headers, 'my_device_serial')
result_A = reader.read_setting_A()
result_B = reader.read_setting_B()
result_C = reader.read_setting_C()
```

For these relatively simple query it does give the correct output. I want to be sure of this approach before implementing more complex queries.

```bash
print(result_A.json())
print(result_B.json())
print(result_C.json())

> {'data': {'value': val_A}}
> {'data': {'value': val_B}}
> {'data': {'value': val_C}}
```

While this already feels like a significant improvement (and notably also an easily expandable option for more complex API calls than simple reads) over individually defined functions, I'd rather do it fully right this time around than having to rewrite this code again in the future.

Do you agree a class (and this implementation) is the correct approach for this issue, and are there any changes you'd suggest?

Comment: The code looks like it might be demo code rather than real working code from a project you have written. If it is demo code then the question is off-topic. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is not demo code, but real working code from a project of mine. I have removed it out its context and given the variables more generic names, thereby only sharing the details relevant for the scope of the question. If it looks like demo code this could be due to my inexperience with Classes generally, as stated.

Comment: Why do your settings have a numeric ID at all? They should be keyed by their unique name as a string.

Comment: I did not design the API I am connecting too, and am simply using the IDs as defined by the API itself. This is not a public API, which is why the domain/output (which work as intended) are dummies. I'm guessing the original developer opted for numeric IDs due to their quantity, ~200. I too find these numeric IDs insufficiently clear, which is my reason for mapping them to unique names (setting_A, ...) for my purposes. I do not expect the settings associated with the IDs to change, I could foresee more settings being added, though these will likely not be used in my current projects scope.

Comment: We need the context of the code to do a good code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can try the approach of creating the methods dynamically. The answer posted by Linny is one way of doing this. Linny's solution implements a `__getattr__` that is called when an attribute such as `read_setting_A` is undefined when calling `reader.read_setting_A()` and then sees if the `read_setting_A` is a key in `self.settings_id` and if so returns an appropriate lambda function for the missing attribute.  If the function should be called again, the `read_setting_A` attribute will still be undefined and the `__getattr__` method will be invoked again.

Let me suggest two approaches, the second of which is the best if you are willing to access the setting values as read/only properties rather than as method calls:

### Approach 1: Create the Class with All Required Methods Up Front

We can define a function `create_SettingReader_class` that returns a class definition with all the necessary methods defined based on your `settings_ids` dictionary, called `SETTINGS_IDS` in the following code:

```py
def create_SettingReader_class():
    import requests
    import types

    SETTINGS_IDS = {
        'setting_A': 1,
        'setting_B': 2,
        'setting_C': 3,
    }

    # Define the methods we will always have:

    def __init__(self, domain, headers, device_serial):
        self.domain = domain
        self.headers = headers
        self.device_serial = device_serial

    def _read_setting(self, setting_id):
        """For demo purposes, just return the setting_id argument."""

        print('_read_setting called with setting_id =', setting_id, 'domain =', self.domain)
        return setting_id

        """
        url = f'{self.domain}/device/{self.device_serial}/settings/{setting_id}/read'
        response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=self.headers)
        return response
        """


    def create_read_setting_function(value):
        """Create a method that calls self._read_setting with the specified
        value as the argument. Note that this function returns a closure."""
        return lambda self: self._read_setting(value)

    # Create a dictionary wuth the methods
    # we will always have:
    cls_dict = {
        '__init__': __init__,
        '_read_setting': _read_setting
    }

    # Add to this dictionary dynamically created methods, one for
    # each key/value pair in SETTINGS_ID. For example, method
    # read_setting_A will be created and it will call _read_setting
    # with the setting_id argument set to 1:
    cls_dict.update({
        'read_' + setting_id: create_read_setting_function(value)
            for setting_id, value in SETTINGS_IDS.items()
    })

    # Return the new class to be assigned to a global variable SettingReader:
    return types.new_class('SettingReader', (), {}, lambda ns: ns.update(cls_dict))

SettingReader = create_SettingReader_class()

domain = "https://my_dummy_api.com"
headers = {"Authorization": "my_token"}

reader = SettingReader(domain, headers, 'my_device_serial')
result_A = reader.read_setting_A()
result_B = reader.read_setting_B()
result_C = reader.read_setting_C()
```

Prints:

```None
_read_setting called with setting_id = 1 domain = https://my_dummy_api.com
_read_setting called with setting_id = 2 domain = https://my_dummy_api.com
_read_setting called with setting_id = 3 domain = https://my_dummy_api.com
```

### A Second Approach: Use Descriptors

[Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) are very powerful. Properties are implemented as descriptors and we will be creating specialized properties. Now a client will access property `setting_A` rather than calling method `read_setting_A`.  If you do not mind the change of syntax, I believe this is a simpler approach than the previous one:

```py
class SettingProperty:
    @staticmethod
    def read_setting(setting_id, domain, headers, device_serial):
        """For demo purposes, just return the setting_id argument."""

        print('read_setting called with setting_id =', setting_id, 'domain =', domain)
        return setting_id

        """
        url = f'{domain}/device/{device_serial}/settings/{setting_id}/read'
        response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers)
        return response
        """

    def __init__(self, setting_id):
        self._setting_id = setting_id

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        """We aren't really interested in the name of this property."""

        self._name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return SettingProperty.read_setting(
            self._setting_id,
            obj.domain,
            obj.headers,
            obj.device_serial)

class SettingReader:
    # Now instead of a dictionary, we have:
    setting_A = SettingProperty(1)
    setting_B = SettingProperty(2)
    setting_C = SettingProperty(3)

    def __init__(self, domain, headers, device_serial):
        self.domain = domain
        self.headers = headers
        self.device_serial = device_serial

domain = "https://my_dummy_api.com"
headers = {"Authorization": "my_token"}

reader = SettingReader(domain, headers, 'my_device_serial')
result_A = reader.setting_A
result_B = reader.setting_B
result_C = reader.setting_C
```

Prints:

```None
read_setting called with setting_id = 1 domain = https://my_dummy_api.com
read_setting called with setting_id = 2 domain = https://my_dummy_api.com
read_setting called with setting_id = 3 domain = https://my_dummy_api.com
```

### Notes

In both approaches when a read-setting method is called or a setting property is accessed, a new request is made to get the value. If this value does not change from call to call, then it could be saved as an attribute in the `SettingReader` instance. Naturally you would check to see if the attribute exists before issuing a network request.

This is the modified code for the second approach that caches the setting values:

```py
class SettingProperty:
    @staticmethod
    def read_setting(setting_id, domain, headers, device_serial):
        """For demo purposes, just return the setting_id argument."""

        print('read_setting called with setting_id =', setting_id, 'domain =', domain)
        return setting_id

        """
        url = f'{domain}/device/{device_serial}/settings/{setting_id}/read'
        response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers)
        return response
        """

    def __init__(self, setting_id):
        self._setting_id = setting_id

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        """Now we are interested in the property's name."""
        self._name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        attribute_name = '_' + self._name
        value = getattr(obj, attribute_name, None)
        if value is None:
            # We must go out to the network:
            value = SettingProperty.read_setting(
                self._setting_id,
                obj.domain,
                obj.headers,
                obj.device_serial)
            setattr(obj, attribute_name, value)
        return value

class SettingReader:
    # Now instead of a dictionary, we have:
    setting_A = SettingProperty(1)
    setting_B = SettingProperty(2)
    setting_C = SettingProperty(3)

    def __init__(self, domain, headers, device_serial):
        self.domain = domain
        self.headers = headers
        self.device_serial = device_serial

domain = "https://my_dummy_api.com"
headers = {"Authorization": "my_token"}

reader = SettingReader(domain, headers, 'my_device_serial')
print(reader.setting_A)
print(reader.setting_A)
```

Prints:

```None
read_setting called with setting_id = 1 domain = https://my_dummy_api.com
1
1
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, learned a great deal from it when you first shared it and implemented many of its design ideas into my project. Since then, my project goals have shifted requiring async requests. My first instinct for this is to have a class similar to your second approach, ensuring the instance gets passed a `httpx.AsyncClient` for the requests, and instead of returning the results returning a coroutine that can be tasked & awaited externally. Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: Sounds feasible -- perhaps something like [this](https://ideone.com/VFzq7g)?

Comment: I've managed to fully implement that and integrate it within my project for the reader class. Thank you! My project (unsurprisingly) also has a `WriteSetting` class, with similar functionality but for writing. I love how clean this approach is, but I don't see how I could transfer it to writing (as `__set__`, lacking a return,  is not viable here).
Is the only option here to have a write setting class with all the setting methods manually defined?

Comment: Sorry - I am not understanding what you are saying. Are you saying that because the descriptor `__set__` method does not return a value, you cannot use a descriptor? If so, why would you need for it to return a value?

Comment: Apologies, I should've been clearer. As I require the return both to confirm the execution and for further processing `__set__` cannot be used. To stay within the scope of code review, [I've build a separate Writer Class that I think has the functionality I desire](https://ideone.com/YTyoAl), by using `__call__`. Do you see any issues with this approach or do you have any notes on how to improve it?

Comment: I think it is time to post your code as a new code review request. Besides being a new issue, you would have a larger audience of potential reviewers. If you do create a new post, you can respond with a comment here to the new link.

Comment: Good call, I have just [posted the new issue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/290846). Still new to SE Code Review, so I appreciate the advice on the guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

### Dynamic Method Creating

Instead of creating a method for each setting, you can dynamically create methods based on the setting names. This makes it a lot easier to call specific settings without having to write these methods yourself, while also making it more scalable and easier to maintain.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    prefix = 'read_setting_'
    if name.startswith(prefix):
        setting_name = name[len(prefix):]
        if setting_name in self.setting_ids:
            return lambda: self._read_setting(self.setting_ids[setting_name])
    raise AttributeError(f"'SettingReader' object has no attribute '{name}'")
```

### Error Handling

Right now, if you pass in an invalid request, everything fails horribly. Add a simple `raise` to help the user know what went wrong.

```
if setting_id is not None:
    return lambda: self._read_setting(setting_id)
else:
    raise ValueError(f"Setting '{setting_name}' not found.")
```